# Scrape posts and comments from a public facebook page

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, web-scraping

It looks like sometime last year, Facebook started severely restricting its Graph API. I've tried different ways to scrape a public facebook page but always get the error: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

Has anyone successfully scraped a facebook page in recent months since the changes? **Just to clarify: the page owner would be okay with me scraping the information.**

Some things I've tried:

https://github.com/LorenzoMonti/facebook_page_group_comments

https://nocodewebscraping.com/facebook-scraper/

https://www.sourcecon.com/how-to-scrape-data-from-facebook-pages/

https://onlinezhuanjia.com/python-facebook-page-scraper-tool/

I've seen some advice online that says you can create a facebook app and then have it approved within a week by fb. Is this possible for something like scraping posts and comments from a public facebook page? I went ahead and created an "app" on fb but don't really understand how to add code to scrape a page & how the approval process works.

Any help or workarounds would be greatly appreciated! Thank you. :)

Comment: Scraping is not allowed to begin with, you have to use the API, if you want to get any such data from Facebook. _“don't really understand how to add code to scrape a page”_ - then do some more research on that, please – you are not the first person ever trying to get posts and comments from a page via API. Frameworks to help with that kind if stuff surely exist in python, too. _“& how the approval process works”_ - that is pretty extensively documented under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review

Comment: Hi 04FS, thank you for the response. The owner of the facebook page wants me to scrape the info for some analysis, so I was hoping fb would allow a workaround. And yes, I want to use the Graph API. I found plenty of code using the Graph API **prior** to the restrictions (none of which work now). I have not found a single example detailing the process in recent months.

Comment: Well then _public_ access is the wrong way to go about this to begin with. You have a user with admin access to the page, so have them log in to your app and grant it permission to access their page. Everything regarding “public access” doesn’t even come into play in this scenario.

Comment: That is good advice. I will try to request access from the admin. The reason I have not done so before is that the admin is not readily available to me, so it might take several weeks to get it approved. But if it's the only way, then that's how it will be.

Answer (score 0):

yea use an API key.... if u want to be sneaky, you'll have to figure out a way to mimic what your browser does, thats user agent, headers, cookies, referers, maybe JS
look into requests or selenium chromedriver
people say scraping isn't allowed, but if you keep minimum wait times between queries, you're just doing what the public does when they use a browser.... and that's allowed...

P.S. if you already spammed facebook they might have temporarily banned your IP